# When the submit button is clicked, I want to get the value of a dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the option's value that was selected in a dropdown list when a button is clicked?

```
<select id="d1"><option value="1">One</option>...</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var value = $('#d1').val();
})
```

`$(element).val()` returns the value of any form element.

Comment: Pretty sure I have run into this numerous times, but I'll take your word, no time to try it.

Comment: should that say "var value" not "val value"?